# IMBD análisis por éxito del director

Tags: dbeaver

Quiero ver los diferentes directores y el año en el que mas tuvieron exito y el de menor éxito  por raking estoy usando este y me da el groos en desorden no de mayor a menor como o quiero

```sql
SELECT Director 
, AVG(IMDB_Rating) AS PROM 
, MAX(Gross) AS Grossg 
FROM imdb_top it 
WHERE Released_Year BETWEEN 1920 AND 1931
GROUP BY Director 
ORDER BY Grossg DESC
```

Comment: Tienes un backup de esa tabla para emularla en mi ambiente? Y por cierto esto es MySQL o MSSQL?? Porque `dbeaver` es un DBa.